# Definition of git 'behind'

Tags: git, version-control

If SourceTree tells me that my 'develop' branch is '1 behind' is it saying that 'develop is 1 commit behind remote/develop' or 1 behind the branch that develop was created from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Git, the remote repository and *your repository's last copy of the remote repository* are two separate things. The `fetch` operation updates your repository's copy of the upstream repository, which can otherwise easily fall behind.

A message telling you that your `develop` branch is "1 behind" is telling you that the remote's version of `develop` has a commit newer than your own repository's `develop` branch reference.

To draw it with some simple ASCII art:

- Your repository has commits like this:

  ```
  commit 3  * <-- `develop` points here
            |
  commit 2  *
            |
  commit 1  *
  ```
- The last time Git pulled down a view of the remote repository, it had commits like this:

  ```
  commit 4  * <-- `remotes/(name)/develop` points here
            |
  commit 3  *
            |
  commit 2  *
            |
  commit 1  *
  ```

The "1 behind" message is telling you that you can do a `pull` operation to update your repository's copy, bringing in that "commit 4" (or whatever it is) and updating your local `develop` branch reference so that it matches the `remotes/(name)/develop` branch reference.

Note that if you choose NOT to do this, Git will be perfectly happy letting you do your own commit that diverges from the remote. If you do that, then you will have a merge conflict you need to resolve before you can get back in sync with the remote.

Comment: So, if I have created the branch locally and not pushed it to remote yet, it will not get a 'behind' message because it doesn't exist on remote (yet)?

Comment: That is what I would expect, yes.

Comment: When would I see a message saying that one branch is behind another? For example, when 'develop' is behind 'master'?

Comment: Oh, except if your `develop` is "1 behind" `remotes/(name)/develop`, and then you create a branch `myfeaturebranch` off of `develop`, Git may be able to tell you that `myfeaturebranch` is tracking `develop`, and `develop` is behind.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.